# MySql Connection failed to connect database

Tags: c#, mysql

I cannot connect to a MySQL database, I am using xampp. 
It says this error from the code simple error: "Connection to the server failed!"

```
namespace Mysql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        public Form1()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "tut1";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";

            string connString;
            connString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};";

            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: DId you check Firewall?

Comment: What happens when you try to connect? Errors? If so, please include the exact error message(s).

Comment: And add related code only!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I got it working. I fixed it adding SslMode=none.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should be like below

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

below is the structure

server={0};user id={1};password={2};database={3};

You need to specify password as `Pwd`